# Php prepared statements firt steps error

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I just started learning php prepared statements like one hour ago. And i need some help on converting this function to PDO. Been trying but getting alot of errors.

```
    function titleQuery($ligaBD){
                $query1="SELECT title FROM page WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
                $result1=mysqli_query($ligaBD,$query1);
                $registos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

                return $registos1; 
}
```

And how would stay my connection.php file? Should it stay like this?

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "root";  
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "mpm"; 

$ligaBD = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password","$db_name") or die ("Error");
```

Thanks.

Comment: @AndyLester why not to read a question before commenting?

Comment: I see no `PDO` code here. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Yes i dit it. And you acting like a professor eheh Im just starting PDO (:

Comment: @miguelfsf There is some functional `MySQLi` code in your question, but no `PDO` code. Maybe you are confusing the two? And yeah, well, you will not learn anything if we just do it for you. Showing us what you have tried, and telling us what the problem is, means that you are actually thinking about the problem and that you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert this function to PDO you need to use PDO stuff.

```
function titleQuery($db,$id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM page WHERE id=?";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($id));
    return $stm->fetchColumn();
}

$title = titleQuery($ligaBD,$_GET['id']);
```

connection.php

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$ligaBD = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password, $opt);
```

Comment: Im going to try this and then i will say something. Thanks alot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

how do i get the result of the query into a variable on PDO?

Getting error "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array" on this line :

```
if($stm['acess'] == 0){ echo'.....'; }
```

The commented code on the function is the code that im trying to convert from mysqli to PDO

```
function checkPageAcess($ligaBD,$acess){ // Check if page is Private or Public
            /*$registos1=titleQuery($ligaBD,$_GET['id']);

            $query2= "SELECT acess FROM statistic WHERE id_page IN(SELECT id FROM page WHERE title='".$registos1['title']."')";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($ligaBD,$query2);
            $registos2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

            if($registos2['acess']==0){
                echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Easy Page Builder</title></head><body>This page is private.</body></html>';exit;
            }*/


            $sql = "SELECT acess FROM statistic WHERE id_page IN(SELECT id FROM page WHERE title=?)";
            $stm = $ligaBD->prepare($sql);
            $stm->execute(array($acess));
            $stm->fetchColumn();

            if($stm['acess'] == 0){
                echo '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Easy Page Builder</title></head><body>This page is private.</body></html>';exit;
            }
    }
    $acess = checkPageAcess($ligaBD,$title);
```